# How to show & change different states of a system for supply chain

Tags: dropdown, sliders, application-state, shipping

Two ways I can think of in regards to supply chain is a drop down showing order status such as not started, processed shipped. Or a slider like mechanism showing progress towards the end similar to how shipping sites do it.

Are there any other ways to do this and any best practices to consider?

States would be not started, in the process, shipped, arrived, canceled.

The drop-down you wouldn't be able to see all of them at the same time so I think that is less desirable, however, if you need to manually change the state that may be preferred.

The current design is below. I Think it is redundant to have both but If the user can change the status I am not sure I like the slider with notches over the drop down.

[image]

Comment: do you have a mock showing your efforts so far, and some context about the views where this is applied?

Comment: great idea above is the two ideas i was thinking of with the post it note as a talking point for the statuses. I think i would do one or the other not both.

Comment: So... this is a user editable progress bar?

Comment: Yes it is. Shows the status of the order and allows them to change it as they progress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are two other designs i came up with. I think i will do the later as it takes up less space but still shows all options and kind of related to the order they would progress in. 
[image]

[image]